# Moving magento1.9 site to new server and domain causes css not to load?

Tags: magento-1.9

We moved a magento 1.9 based site to a new server and a new domain name. now when we go to the site most of the images and pages load. However no css or js seem to be loading and doing a view source I see the links to css files are missing the /skin/ in the url ??

I made sure in the core_config_database that there is an ending slash on the sites url. However i am not sure what else i am missing? I do see a .htaccess file in the magento root folder.

Comment: There are 3 URLs ... base, media and skin URLs. You have to change all of them.

Comment: ahh ok thanks. Forgot about the skin url column in the database.

Comment: Just added this as answer ... fell free to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 URLs types ... base, media and skin URLs. You have to change all of them.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like below (if you are not using CDN)

[image]

Comment: You're more right. 5 - not 3 - URL types ... +1 :)